# python:AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'math'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a very simple python script. But it gives me some error. Below is the script:

RS is list of some numbers like 0.4486449

```
co_D = []
for z in RS:
    t = 1.0 + z # set t = 1 + z
    y = 1.80502*t - 0.51058*math.pow(t,2) + 0.087877*math.pow(t,3) - 0.0088272*math.pow(t,4) + 0.0004744.math.pow(t,5) - 0.000010515*math.pow(t,6)
    D = (y - 1.3739537) * 4282.7429
    co_D.append(D)
```

And then it says **"AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'math'
"**
How do I correct it to avoid such errors?

Comment: Typo: `0.0004744.math.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You managed to replace a `*` with a `.` here:

```
0.0004744.math.pow(t,5)
#        ^
```

This is one of the reasons the Python style guide recommends you put spaces around operators; to make this more easily spottable.

The corrected line would be:

```
y = (
    1.80502 * t - 
    0.51058 * math.pow(t, 2) + 
    0.087877 * math.pow(t, 3) -
    0.0088272 * math.pow(t, 4) +
    0.0004744 * math.pow(t, 5) -
    0.000010515 * math.pow(t, 6))
```

Comment: @HuanianZhang if this answer helped solve your problem, please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it by clicking on the check mark next to it.